# How can I show local notifications on Apple Watch using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I've made a simple test app that schedules a notification for 5 seconds later, and checks to see that it's scheduled, and although this code works in iOS (shows a notification after 5 seconds) it does not on Apple Watch.  I'm wondering what more I have to do or add to have these notifications successfully delivered and seen.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var numberOfRequests = 0

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(
                action: {
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                        if success {
                            print("All set!")
                        } else if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: { Text("Request") }
            )
            Button(
                action: {
                    
                    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                    content.title = "Feed the cat"
                    content.subtitle = "It looks hungry"
                    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"

                    // show this notification five seconds from now
                    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)

                    // choose a random identifier
                    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

                    // add our notification request
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                    
                },
                label: { Text("Set notification") }
            )
            Button(
                action: {
                    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                    
                    notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
                        
                        print("The are \(requests.count) requests!")
                        self.numberOfRequests = requests.count
                        
                    }
                        
                        
                        )
                },
                label: { Text("Show notifications") }
            )
            Text("\(self.numberOfRequests)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you been you succesful finding the answer? Thanks

Comment: I have... in short I needed to add this
```swift
extension LocalNotifications: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
    ) {
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```
If you're stuck on this problem, I'll write a longer explanation later.

Comment: could use your help. I am stuck on the same spot... where do you put this extension? thx!